# How do I determine if a constant function from another library is called in a class method using jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

My react component (class) method uses a constant function from another library. I have to write a test whether that function is called under certain conditions, if I call my class method. I cannot mock the function because it is a constant function.

I tried using

```
jest.spyOn(library, 'const_function')
myClass.methodUnderTest()
```

And then checking with

```
expect(library.const_function).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Although the console.log just above to call in the my class is running, jest insists that

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

received 0 calls.

I also tried

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(library, 'const_function')
```

And then checked whether "spy" was called with no success.

How can I achieve such a simple goal using jest?

Comment: What does the const_function look like? Is there any error?

Comment: no errors thrown. even if I empty the const_function, the call to it is not detected. I just added a console.log into const_function and I get to see the log, but no detection by jest. I guess jest just cannot do it.

Comment: The library like this `export const_function = function() {}`?

Comment: @slideshowp2 export const const_function = () => {
  console.log("CALL")
}

Answer (score 0):

You should use `import * as library from './library'` statement, then you can use `jest.spyOn` add spy on the `library.const_function`.

E.g.

`library.js`:

```js
export const const_function = () => {
  console.log('CALL');
};
```

`library.test.js`:

```js
import * as library from './library';

describe('61754429', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    jest.spyOn(library, 'const_function');
    library.const_function();
    expect(library.const_function).toHaveBeenCalled();
    library.const_function.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61754429/library.test.js (11.147s)
  61754429
    ✓ should pass (23ms)

  console.log
    CALL

      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.const_function (stackoverflow/61754429/library.js:2:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.768s
```

**UPDATE**

`myclass.js`:

```js
import * as library from './library';

export class MyClass {
  methodUnderTest() {
    return library.const_function();
  }
}
```

`myclass.test.js`:

```js
import { MyClass } from './myclass';
import * as library from './library';

describe('61754429', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    jest.spyOn(library, 'const_function');
    const myclass = new MyClass();
    myclass.methodUnderTest();
    expect(library.const_function).toHaveBeenCalled();
    library.const_function.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61754429/myclass.test.js (16.117s)
  61754429
    ✓ should pass (54ms)

  console.log
    CALL

      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.const_function (stackoverflow/61754429/library.js:2:11)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 library.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 myclass.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        20.913s
```

Comment: This function is imported in a react component (class) and a method in the class calls this function. When I call that method in the class, this function is called. I want to check this.

Comment: I have edited my question to make the problem clearer.

Comment: @schlingel Updated answer, please check.

Comment: interesting, your output shows no issues but I cannot make it work on my machine. I have other job to do, I will try with a clean environment and let you know.